# Statement lambda in Any(LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, lambda, any

I have a little problem with my code and maybe I'm blind but i don't see any problem

```
   prefabPool.Any( bullet => 
                                {
                                    if(bullet.activeSelf == false)
                                    {
                                        bullet.SetActive(true);
                                        return true;
                                    }   
                                    return false;  
                                }; 
                                );
```

This is my lambda statement and the compiler gives me an error at 9 row

**) expected [Assembly-CSharp]csharp(CS1026)**

And I actually don't know what is the problem because my syntax seems good

Answer (score 2):

This bit:

```
}; // This is still a parameter inside the .Any( )
);
```

Only needs the last semicolon:

```
});
```

Comment: I messed up the syntax... I thought that the rule is : (input-parameters) => { <sequence-of-statements> }; with semicolon at the end. Thank you!!!

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 1):

`.Any()` will stop once it finds one match. IMHO using `.Any()` with a lambda that has side effects makes your code less readable.

In your case I would replace with;

```cs
    prefabPool.FirstOrDefault(b => !b.activeSelf)?.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It's more readable than mine